# c# how to change the tray icon

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, trayicon

I'm still learning C# and I'm stuck. My problem is that I have a tray icon, which has to be changed when somthing happens.

I have added the new icon as an existing item to the project and I'm trying to change it by using this code:

```
this.notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(GetType(), "newmailIcon.ico");
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Resource 'newmailIcon.ico' cannot be found in class 'Traym_Icon.Form1'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually add your `newmailIcon.ico` as a resource file in your project.

Comment: You also have to change the properties, build action of it. Its a resource, not code, and it should be embedded.

Comment: Try setting Build Action to either `Resource` or `Embedded Resource` and compile the project again

Comment: Already did this. No idea why it is still showing the same error :'(

Comment: Last thing I can suggest is to scrap `GetType()`. This should use the `newmailIcon.ico` file in the directory as the Icon, instead of searching for it as a compiled resource.

Answer (score 4):

right click on your image, click propereties and at the Build action, choose Embed.

or create a .resx in which you will keep your icons.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you didn't mean 'class', you meant newmailIcon.ico right?

Comment: Hi,thanks for the help,but im still getting the same error... Thats kinda weird,Im sure im doing somthing wrong